# Hibernate ignores Converter

Tags: java, hibernate, converters

I am getting `ClassCastException: at.sheldor5.tr.api.time.RecordType cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean` because Hibernate 5.2.9.FINAL completly ignores my converter:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="at.sheldor5.tr.api.time">
    <class name="Record" table="RECORDS">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="PK_RECORD_ID">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" column="FK_USER_MAPPING_ID" class="at.sheldor5.tr.api.user.UserMapping"/>
        <property name="date" type="java.time.LocalDate" column="DATE" index="I_DATE"/>
        <property name="time" type="java.time.LocalTime" column="TIME"/>
        <property name="type" type="boolean" column="TYPE">
            <type name="at.sheldor5.tr.persistence.converter.RecordTypeAttributeConverter"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Converter:

```
@Converter
public class RecordTypeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<RecordType, Boolean> {
  @Override
  public Boolean convertToDatabaseColumn(final RecordType attribute) {
    if (attribute == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return attribute.getBoolean();
  }

  @Override
  public RecordType convertToEntityAttribute(final Boolean dbData) {
    return RecordType.getType(dbData);
  }
}
```

The only thing I can see is that hibernate ignores my converter because of some random things.

Any suggestions (except clean/rebuild which I already tried or hard reset)?

EDIT: my converter won't even gets loaded ...

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you shouldn't use `type="boolean"` attribute here? Move your converter classname to `type` attribute. i.e. https://pastebin.com/5KgipkQb

Comment: Gives me: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: at.sheldor5.tr.persistence.converter.RecordTypeAttributeConverter, at table: RECORDS, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(TYPE)]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30620642/4024558 . Did you declare your converter in `persistence.xml`?

Comment: @TarwirdurTuron the persistence.xml gets ignored as well ...